# Python For Loop Debug In Spyder

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, debugging

I have written some python code to combine many small .csv files into one large excel file. The code works fine but every now and then a rogue .csv file in the wrong format causes a crash. I thought I could use the debugger feature on Spyder to easily identify the dodgy csv file but alas it is not listed in the variable explorer window. I would simply like to know the value of 'f'  in the code below when the program crashes:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[0,1,2], header=None) for f in all_filenames])
```

So I tried to replace the line with:

```
for f in all_filenames:
    combined_csv = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[0,1,2], header=None))
```

And now getting an error (TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame") when it is first called so I guess I haven't done this right?

Comment: You can use for loop instead of list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop instead of the the list eventually led to me finding the offending files:

```
dflist = []
for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[0,1,2], header=None)
    dflist.append(df)
combined_csv = pd.concat(dflist)
```